# Нашёл программу с условием, которая выводит возраст, на Python 3.8.2, но встретил ошибку, с которой никак не могу справиться, помогите, пожалуйста!

Tags: python

[image: Красным выделена ошибка]

Нашёл программу с условием, которая выводит возраст, на Python 3.8.2, но встретил ошибку, с которой никак не могу справиться, помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Неплохо было бы почитать сначала про синтаксис языка и о том какую роль в нем играют отступы

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы взяли и скопировали в `консоль Python IDLE` код. Консоль для этого не предназначена.

Чтобы выполнить скопированный код в сценарном режиме нажмите `File`, затем `New File`. В открывшееся окно вставляете свой код. Сохраняете файл сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl + s` с расширением `.py`(*точка пай, не точка ру*). Затем нажатием клавиши `F5` запускаете свой код.

Читайте про [Python IDLE](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pervaya-programma-sreda-razrabotki-idle.html).